# extracting data from an xml file

Tags: c#, xml

I have a string XML, which I want to convert to an actual XML, and get its values.

My (string)XML document looks like that:

```
<Folder>
    <Files>
       <File Id="123" 
        Size="111"
        Name="abc"/>
    </Files>
</Folder>
```

This is what I'm doing:

```
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.LoadXml(stringXML);

XmlNodeList xnList = xml.SelectNodes("/Folder/Files");
foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList)
{
     string a = xn["File Id"].InnerText;
}
```

Here, my `xml` variable (the XmlDocument) has my XML: `< Folder>< Files>` etc... inside the "InnerXml" property.
The `xnList` (XmlNodeList) has `< File Id="123" Size="111" Name="abc"/>` under its "InnerXml" property.
and `xn` the XmlNode is exactly the same as xnList, so there is no such thing as `xn["File Id"]`.

How can I get the information from the XML file?

Comment: Your XML is not valid. Id="123" is not allowed as an element

Comment: This isn't any valid XML. I doubt if you can term that <ID="123".../> can be termed as XmlNodeList (For that matter any XML tag). An XML tag will always have some name. This doesn't have any, than just attributes.

Comment: it was an example.. i changed if to "fileid"

Comment: Even 'FileId' not valid It should be something like <FileId id="123"/>

Comment: @user990635: If you're going to give an example, make it a realistic one, with valid XML. How are we meant to guess what your *real* XML looks like? (And can you use LINQ to XML? It makes this sort of thing simpler...)

Comment: it was file id.. my bad.. still, the problem is with this inner xml, that all the file attributes are in the inner xml, and i need to get each one separately.. id, size, name, etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not really clear what you're trying to do, but I'd suggest using LINQ to XML - it'll make things simpler:

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(stringXML);
// Or doc.Root.Element("Files").Elements("File")
foreach (var file in doc.Descendants("File")) 
{
    int id = (int) file.Attribute("Id");
    int size = (int) file.Attribute("Size");
    string name = (string) file.Attribute("Name");
    // Do whatever you need...
}
```

Or if you just want to gather the information:

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(stringXML);
var query = doc.Descendants("File").Select(file => new { 
                                Id = (int) file.Attribute("Id"),
                                Size = (int) file.Attribute("Size"),
                                Name = (string) file.Attribute("Name")
                            });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct way:

```
        var stringXML = "<Folder><Files><File Id=\"123\" Size=\"111\" Name=\"abc\"/></Files></Folder> ";
        XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
        xml.LoadXml(stringXML);

        XmlNodeList xnList = xml.SelectNodes("/Folder/Files");
        foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList)
        {
            string a = xn["File"].Attributes["Id"].Value;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't straight a way fetch the attribute value for Id. You can use the attribute property to fetch that particular attribute value.

```
 XmlNodeList xnList = xml.SelectNodes("/Folder/Files");
    foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList)
    {
         string a = xn.Attributes["Id"].Value; // Modify likewise
    }
```